# Why mobx computed getter doesn't call after change value

Tags: mobx, mobx-react, mobx-react-lite

I have `TestStore` and observable property `fields`.

When I click to any name, i call action `changeOneName` and change some object inside `fields`. Computed getter `hasError` called again and i see `console.log("hasError computed");`

Why don't I see  `console.log("valueFields computed");` second time after changing name to `'ErrorName'`?

https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-lumiere-cv2tp?file=/src/TestStore.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only changed `name` property of the object, not the object itself. And `Object.values` only dereferences direct values (objects) of your `fields` object, not the inner things, like `name`. So `computed` don't need to rerun because things that were referenced in that `computed` didn't change.

`hasError` did rerun because you actually dereference `name` property inside of it, so when `name` changes it reruns.

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Rerender happens because your whole App component is `observer` (which is more or less the same as `computed`, but for React components) and you dereference `name` inside its render. Component essentially subscribes for changes to every field you dereference inside of the render (inside of function basically).